# Provide default value to properties in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've learning SwiftUI for a week, recently I found a confusing issue with it.

```
@State private var checkAmount = 0.0
    var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    
                    Section {
                        TextField("Amount", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    }
                    
    
        
                    Section{
                        Text(checkAmount, format:.currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                    }
                    
                }
     
            }

    }
```

I use `TextFile` to receive user's input and alter the value of `checkAmount`, and make the value shown in the section below. Here is my preview in xcode.
[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrW33.png)
But when I type a random number and delete it all, this happend:
[Still a digit here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfEM9.png)

It seems SwiftUI didn't delete it all, and still keep the last digit I deleted.

I guess maybe I should give it an default value when user's input is empty?

Some additional information maybe necessary: I'm using a M1 MacMini and XCode 14.1

Comment: This seems like a major oversight by the SwiftUI team. You could use a string text field and do the manual formatting etc, but it's a bit of a pain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Approach

- For `currency(code:)` the value type is `Decimal`, so you have to use **`Optional Decimal`**
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/parseableformatstyle/3796617-currency
- When the last digit is deleted it becomes `nil`
- Use `checkAmount ?? 0` in your `TextField`

## Code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var checkAmount = Decimal?(0.0) //Optional decimal

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Amount", value: $checkAmount, format: .currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                }
                Section{
                    //Use ?? operator to display 0 when nil
                    Text(checkAmount ?? 0, format:.currency(code: Locale.current.currency?.identifier ?? "USD"))
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: checkAmount) { newValue in
                print("checkAmount = \(String(describing: newValue))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```